# Issues with getting TCP Client send only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, tcplistener

I am currently trying to do a TCP that only sends out data without the need of any response, meaning that the server side only listens to TCP message.

This is the Java Config for the Client side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TcpClientConfig implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

@Value("${tcp.server.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${tcp.server.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${tcp.client.connection.poolSize}")
private int connectionPoolSize;

private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

@Override
public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNetClientConnectionFactory, connectionPoolSize);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler outboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}
```

This is the TcpClientGateway

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outboundChannel")
public interface TcpClientGateway {

    void send(byte[] message);

}
```

This is a scheduler

```
@Component
@EnableScheduler
public class MessageJobScheduler {

    private MessageService messageService;

    @Autowired
    public MessageJobScheduler(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000L)
    public void sendMessageJob() {
        messageService.sendMessage();
    }

}
```

This is the part where it sends out the messages and receive the response from the server.

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageServiceImpl.class);

    private TcpClientGateway tcpClientGateway;

    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceImpl(TcpClientGateway tcpClientGateway) {
        this.tcpClientGateway = tcpClientGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage() {
        String message = LocalDateTime.now().toString();
        LOGGER.info("Send message: {}", message);
        tcpClientGateway.send(message.getBytes());
    }

}
```

This is the Java Config at the Server side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TcpServerConfig {

    @Value("${tcp.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port);
        return serverConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel inboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway inboundGateway(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory, MessageChannel inboundChannel) {
        TcpInboundGateway tcpInboundGateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
        tcpInboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        tcpInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(inboundChannel);
        return tcpInboundGateway;
    }

}
```

This is the message endpoint from server side

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class TcpServerEndpoint {

    private MessageService messageService;

    @Autowired
    public TcpServerEndpoint(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
    public void process(byte[] message) {
        messageService.processMessage(message);
    }

}
```

At the server side, I just want to receive the TCP message sent from the client side and print out the message without any reply back to the client (acts like a listener only).

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void processMessage(byte[] message) {
        String messageContent = new String(message);
        LOGGER.info("Receive message: {}", messageContent); 
    }

}
```

However, I received this error at the client side with a message timeout exception. The TcpOutboundGateway seems to be expecting a reply everytime I sent out a message. This is the error that I get from the console log

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:216)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:161)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:46)
```

Anyone knows how can I set the configurations to be send only at the client side without any response from the server?

Comment: I have a question, why don't you use UDP?

Comment: @tyChen the system I am getting the data from is through TCP so I can't change the protocol

Comment: If you're not expecting a respojse why does your `send()` message return a byte array?

Comment: @user207421 That's one mistake of mine, I've edited my code, changing the `send()` to return void but I still get the same error